# Not a Valid Service SOAP Call

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, exception, soap

I am creating my first SOAP Service and I am getting the error Not a valid Service. Could someone please help me out? I am creating a project for a imaginary belt store. SO my service is supposed to get all the products that are not shipped yet. For now i am just sending it in an array. Once the service starts working i will modify it in a better way.

Below is my error

```
 Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: {http://service.itmd.iit/}OrdersImplService is not a valid service. Valid services are: {http://util.itmd.iit/}OrdersImplService
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:200)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:145)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:93)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Service.java:680)
at iit.itmd.client.Client.main(Client.java:19)
```

Below is my Interface

```
package iit.itmd.service;
import java.util.List;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style=Style.RPC)
@XmlRootElement
public interface Orders {
@WebMethod String[] getNotFulfilled();
}
```

My Order Implementation class which implements the above interface is given below

```
package iit.itmd.util;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.List;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import iit.itmd.service.Orders;
@XmlType
@WebService(endpointInterface="iit.itmd.service.Orders")
public class OrdersImpl implements Orders{

@Override
@XmlElement
public String[] getNotFulfilled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Connection conn=null;
    Statement statement=null;
    int i=0;
    String selecttableSql="select id,customer_id from orders where  status<>'SHIPPED'";
    String[] result=null;
    try{
    DBConn con=new DBConn();
    conn=con.getConnection();
    statement = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(selecttableSql);
    System.out.println(rs.getFetchSize());
    while (rs.next()) {

        String orderId = rs.getString("ID");
        String customerId = rs.getString("CUSTOMER_ID");
        result[i]=orderId;
        result[i]= customerId;
        System.out.println("userid : " + orderId);
        System.out.println("username : " + orderId);

    }}
    catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    } finally {

        if (statement != null) {
            try {
                statement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    return result;
}

}
```

I created a client to call the SOAP Service. The code for the client is below

```
package iit.itmd.client;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import iit.itmd.domain.*;
import iit.itmd.service.Orders;
public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9999/BeltStore/getnotshipped");

    //1st argument service URI, refer to wsdl document above
//2nd argument is service name, refer to wsdl document above
    QName qname = new QName("http://service.itmd.iit/", "OrdersImplService");
    Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
    Orders order = service.getPort(Orders.class);
    System.out.println(order.getNotFulfilled());
}

}
```

Could someone please let me know what i am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: RPC is pretty completely deprecated, sure you need to use it?

Comment: Hello @bmargulies Thanks for the reply. this is just a sample application that i am trying out. I wanted to Learn SOAP Web Services and this is just a starting point.

Comment: Then use 'document' instead of 'rpc'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your client code you specify a namespace for the service, which is good practice, but I don't see that namespace back in your service code. Your service has to define a namespace and this should correspond with the namespace your client uses for specifying the webservice method. E.g.

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://service.itmd.iit/")
```